# Kinect sensor not working?

Tags: ros, gazebo, kinect, turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to see the output of the 3DSensors of the turtlebot in simulation in gazebo.

I am launching turtlebot in gazebo using command:

roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch

then,

roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch

then.

roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch

then, Its showing:

started roslaunch server http:// localhost:53453/

SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /camera/camera_nodelet_manager/num_worker_threads
- /camera/depth_rectify_depth/interpolation
- /camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth/interpolation
- /camera/disparity_depth/max_range
- /camera/disparity_depth/min_range
- /camera/disparity_registered_hw/max_range
- /camera/disparity_registered_hw/min_range
- /camera/disparity_registered_sw/max_range
- /camera/disparity_registered_sw/min_range
- /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url
- /camera/driver/depth_frame_id
- /camera/driver/depth_registration
- /camera/driver/device_id
- /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url
- /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id
- /depthimage_to_laserscan/output_frame_id
- /depthimage_to_laserscan/range_min
- /depthimage_to_laserscan/scan_height
- /rosdistro
- /rosversion

NODES
/camera/
camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_points (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
depth_registered_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
disparity_registered_hw (nodelet/nodelet)
disparity_registered_sw (nodelet/nodelet)
driver (nodelet/nodelet)
points_xyzrgb_hw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
points_xyzrgb_sw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet)
rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)
register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
/
depthimage_to_laserscan (nodelet/nodelet)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http:// localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [5376]
process[camera/driver-2]: started with pid [5399]
[ INFO] [1386525391.401574172]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
process[camera/debayer-3]: started with pid [5434]
process[camera/rectify_mono-4]: started with pid [5450]
process[camera/rectify_color-5]: started with pid [5467]
process[camera/rectify_ir-6]: started with pid [5483]
process[camera/depth_rectify_depth-7]: started with pid [5500]
[ INFO] [1386525391.957140970]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
process[camera/depth_metric_rect-8]: started with pid [5516]
process[camera/depth_metric-9]: started with pid [5534]
process[camera/depth_points-10]: started with pid [5552]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-11]: started with pid [5569]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12]: started with pid [5585]
process[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-13]: started with pid [5603]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-14]: started with pid [5621]
process[camera/disparity_depth-15]: started with pid [5639]
process[camera/disparity_registered_sw-16]: started with pid [5656]
process[camera/disparity_registered_hw-17]: started with pid [5672]
process[depthimage_to_laserscan-18]: started with pid [5690]
[ INFO] [1386525394.962265431]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1386525397.966016741]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected

PLZ help anyone...
THANKS in advance...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108171/kinect-sensor-not-working?/) by [DPK27](https://answers.ros.org/users/9621/dpk27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assumes that you are using hydro.

To simulate turtlebot, you don't have to launch minimal and 3d sensor. You can control both 3d sensor and robot with the command below.

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
```

or

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_playground.launch
```

/camera/depth/points will give you 3d data. check with this command

```
rostopic bw /camera/depth/points
```

or bringup rviz and see.

```
roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_robot.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2013-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0